# История выполнения функций в Django

Tags: python, django

Вопрос от новичка.

В [Статье](https://russianblogs.com/article/45611627794/) рассматривается, что происходит после вызова команды *manage.py runserver*

Есть ли какой-либо способ увидеть это в виде "журнала" или подобного функционала не только после вызова этой конкретной команды, но и после любых действий например в админке и т.д.?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `увидеть это` - что именно увидеть?

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA Какие функции вызываются по порядку